# delete duplicate record using rank() function in cte

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
   with DeleteDUplicateinXYZ
    as
    (
     Select ID, rank()over( order by Id Asc) as [rank] 
     from ppp        -----------never use 'partion by' while using rank
    )Delete from DeleteDUplicateinXYZ 
    where [rank] in (Select id, count([rank]) 
    from DeleteDUplicateinXYZ group by Id having count([rank]) >=2)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you are trying to do here.  Your current delete query makes no sense.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  Also, I don't see a clear problem statement.